# Unable to read client-cert and client-key when trying to run kubectl get pods with minikube

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, kubernetes, minikube

I'm on Ubuntu linux VM and trying to run minikube on it.

I installed kubectl via homebrew and then installed minikube by following below installation guides:
kubectl: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux
minikube: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

I started minikube as `sudo minikube start --driver=none` which has the following output:
[image]

When I run the command: `kubectl get pods`, I get an error:

```
Error in configuration:
* unable to read client-cert /home/jenkins/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt for minikube due to open /home/jenkins/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt: permission denied
* unable to read client-key /home/jenkins/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key for minikube due to open /home/jenkins/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key: permission denied
```

The user I'm installing all above is `/home/jenkins`. I'm not sure what's going wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: did you run `sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube` ?

Comment: any update? `sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube` had to help

Answer (score 3):

From [#8363](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8363#issuecomment-637892712) shared by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70451125/1235675), I did `nano ~/.kube/config` and corrected the path..

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/username/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.64.3:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/username/.minikube/profiles/client.crt
    client-key: /home/username/.minikube/profiles/client.key
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 typical scenarios for such situations: either your keys were not created during minikube installation either you dont have proper permissions from your user.

For 1st case(not your) - you will clearly see in logs `no such file or directory`. To know more and how to resolve it  - please refer to [Unable to read client-cert/key Post Minikube Update](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8363#issuecomment-637885532)

2nd is yours: **client.crt: permission denied**.
Your current user doesnt have proper rights to read the file.

Resolution inside your screenshot. You should run below commands after cluster was created.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the minikube with `minikube start --embed-certs`.
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/untrusted_certs/.

Answer (score 0):

yes i changed the paths from windows style to unix style and it works (minikube)

Answer (score 0):

You can try full reinstall and then start it with cert refresh using commands below:

```
minikube delete --all=true --purge=true
minikube start --embed-certs
```